# Https certificate error, WCF service on IIS

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis, https, x509certificate

I want to organize secured connection between a client and WCF service. The client must be sured, that it can trust the service.

I've create two certificate for Trusted Root and for Personal storages on the local machine. I can see the correct certification path in the certificate add-on.
The certificate common name is localhost.

I've added the binding for https on IIS.

I have the service with the following config

Behaviour

```
    <behavior name="AgencyTrustedServiceBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000" />
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"  />
        </clientCertificate>

        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />

      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

Binding

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="InternetServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None">
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Endpoint

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AgencyTrustedServiceBehavior" name="Megatec.MasterTourService.AuthService">
    <endpoint address="Anonymous" 
              binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="InternetServiceBinding" 
              name="Megatec.MasterTourService.Contracts.IAuthServiceAnonymous" 
              contract="Megatec.MasterTourService.Contracts.IAuthService">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
```

But, when I try access the service by using WCFTestClient, it throw the following exception

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/IISTest/AuthService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.    The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost/IISTest/AuthService.svc    The document at the url http://localhost/IISTest/AuthService.svc was not recognized as a known document type.The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading 'https://dev4-10.megatec.ru/IISTest/AuthService.svc?disco'.'.  
- The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.  
- The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
- Report from 'http://localhost/IISTest/AuthService.svc' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
```

what is wrong?

Comment: For starters, shouldn't you be using https?

Comment: I use https. I've added https-binding for IIS (with this certificate), I try to access https://localhost/IISTest/AuthService.svc address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL the client is hitting is:

"http://localhost/IISTest/AuthService"

It should be

"https://localhost/IISTest/AuthService"

Comment: I've solved this - WCF test client automatically use http://localhost/IISTest/AuthService.svc instead of https://localhost/IISTest/AuthService.svc. When I've added the service with address https://localhost/IISTest/AuthService, it works.